# Getting an oAuth2 access token for EWS (SOAP)

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

We are using Exchange Web Services (SOAP) to add appointments to Office 365 mailboxes and want to implement oAuth2 authentication for that.

The existing documentation does not really cover this use case, and there are two ways to register an app: in Azure Management Portal (old way) and in the Application Registration portal (new way).

There are some guides for the new way, but they all use https://graph.microsoft.com as an endpoint, and we need https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx.

We use a certificate and build a client assertion, but we cannot get a token with the audience claim of https://outlook.office365.com.

The closest thing found is: https://chriswood.me/azure-active-directory-v2-and-exchange-web-services/

which taught us how to configure the permissions in the manifest (since the new Application registration Portal lacks the UI to do it). Here we skipped a step, in that the old Azure Management Portal seems to have changed since the article was written, and I could not recreate the configuration in a (v1) manaifest, so I just merged the posted:

```
{
  "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
  "resourceAccess": [
    {
      "id": "dc890d15-9560-4a4c-9b7f-a736ec74ec40",
      "type": "Role"
    }
  ]
}
```

into my manifest. But then the next step fails if when requesting the token we specify anything but https://graph.microsoft.com.default as the scope:

We request the token from:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenanat ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token

with the payload:

```
client_id={client ID}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJ...
```

but this nets us a JWT with an audience claim of microsoft.graph. As the linked article explains, we need https://outlook.office365.com. How should we format the scope parameter in the payload?

Comment: Fixed in the meantime: the solution is setting the audience claim in the client assertion as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials